# Desktop overheating room, is it CPU, GPU, or PSU?

Tags: cpu, power-supply, gpu, overheating

If my door is shut, my computer turns my room into an oven, it's that bad. I'm hoping replacing a part will resolve the issue. Here's some specs:

CPU: AMD FX 8320 Eight core
GPU: AMD Radeon 6670
PSU: don't even know

here's a screen shot of temperatures taken from CPUID software

[image: cropped CPUID]

Comment: Your BIOS view of fans and temps may indicate a source?

Comment: @Kram i used a tool to get the temperature data, but the data is not meaningful to me

Comment: @Kram i posted the data, wana take a look?

Comment: Your temperatures are not unusually hot though.  Your GPU and CPU temperatures are well below their maximum tolerances.

Comment: Probably just bad ventilation in your room when you shut your door. None of your temperatures are abnormal.

Comment: at what temperature is it worrisome? The highest reading I'm seeing is 74C for the third value under the cpu (10 point increase from when i posted)

Comment: @BenSampica read that comment please

Comment: @Ramhound read that comment please

Comment: The MTBF for silicon processing stuff (general) is worse as the temperatures are higher, but it is very minimally a problem to ~80*C where the (small) possiblity of a error or fail or increased damages starts really going up, The modern procssing chips with extreme perfection and quality build  are speced to be able to cope with ~100*C , and do deal with that for months and months with no problem most of the time.  If there was a great fear of failure or loss, it starts somewhere around 80*C and can still be survivable  to around 100*C.

Comment: @Pycogeek thanks good to know, but getting back to the original question, which is mainly causing the heat? Is it the cpu? will replacing cpu with an intel one make my room less heated?

Comment: @Ragdoll - How are you going to replace an AMD CPU with an Intel CPU on a AMD motherboard.  An Intel CPU isn't going to run much cooler.  Depending on your skill you can remove the heatsink, clean the thermal paste on the CPU, and apply new thermal paste but honestly as I said before those temperatures are not that concerning.  If your machine was unstable that would be a whole different story.

Comment: You did not indicate what you are doing on the computer?  When playing games loading my GPU to 90% the computer heats the room a lot (gpu can be highest power) ,  When encoding videos and not using the GPU but pushing all 4 CPU cores to 100% it heats my room a lot, when doing both , it is like a nice little 400W space heater.  Plus the power conversion losses at the PSU.  Work is one thing that can have the power consumption and output heat increase like a sweaty racehorse :-)

Comment: @psycogeek. I'm not a gamer, but if the GPU can be hot source, is it odd that Ragdoll's GPU current utilisation was 99% - even if the Spec report used some juice to generate?